# Virtual Box: Bridging to Virtual Interface (eth0:1)

Tags: debian, virtualbox, bridge

I have four IP addresses on my Debian machine: 1 main (`eth0`) + 3 extra (`eth0:0`, `eth0:1`, `eth0:2`).

I want to assign the `eth0:1` as bridged network to my VM. Who do I need to add in the `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Virtual interfaces are not real, and don't behave like real interfaces. (They're actually not recommended at all, and can be replaced with multiple addresses attached to a single interface.) They can't be used by iptables, and they can't be used in bridges[0].

If you want to bridge the VM onto the real network then just put eth0 into the bridge. The bridge doesn't need an IP because it's just doing layer 2 forwarding. If you want the VM to use one of the external IPs then put eth0 and the VM in the bridge, and attach the IP inside the actual VM and not on the host at all.

If you really want to use an external IP on the bridge (without putting eth0 in the bridge) you can attach it to the bridge instead of to a virtual interface and use [Proxy ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_ARP) to announce it on the real network.

[0] Well, technically they can, but the real interface gets added.

Comment: Thanks für you answer. I just want to use one of the additional IPs to access my VM. I thought i need to bridge the virtual interface not the main eth0. I'm new in this stuff and i just have a simple HowTo for install VirtualBox, install OS in there, etc... From your answer i think i just need to bridge `eth:0` (`br`) and set `bridge_ports eth0:1`

Comment: Added that to the answer. You want to put eth0 into the bridge, and configure the IP *inside* the VM, not on the host at all.